# Generate two random bit arrays with 90 % same elements

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

I have to generate two random bit arrays. The requirement is to generate arrays with only 10% of bit error rates, i.e the element wise comparison between 2 arrays should give us about 90% elements true.

I generate arrays using rand function separately, it results about 40% to 60% same elements in two arrays. To reduce to 10 % I tried to find the random locations in one array to replace it with 1, but it destroys the randomness. It may not be elegant way, for large numbers it doesn't work (I need to test 10, 000  bits in the array ). Can anyone please suggest me how can I generate two random binary arrays with very less errors.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you [edit] your question to include the code that you're trying to modify?

Comment: Do you want exactly a 10% error rate, no more than 10%, no less, or an average of 10% over many repeated runs?

Comment: less than 10 % error.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming I understand you right, this means the second array is not actually "random". It's dependent on the first array, but then has 10% of its bits flipped (to create the 10% error). Therefore, I suggest you follow the following algorithm:

1. Generate one random bit array
2. Copy this array
3. Randomly select 10% of the elements in the second array, and invert those bits.

Note: If you want exactly 10% error, be sure you're not just selecting a random element `n/10` times because you will inevitably invert the same bit twice. You have to select `n/10` *different* elements to invert. However, if you want a *maximum of 10% error* it may be advantageous to purposely introduce a possibility of re-inverting an individual bit (and thus correcting it).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my requirement is to generate arrays in different machines (in client and server).I am doing error correction coding. I need to make sure that two arrys have less than 10 % error, before error correction.

Comment: If you have to do this on two separate machines that cannot talk to each other (I am still not sure why), the only thing you can do is use a deterministic PRNG, and seed them both with the same value. (With the same seed, you'll get the same output.) Then apply the above algorithm to one of the arrays.

Comment: @user3744763 it's easy initial bit array simulates the initial bits dispatched from the source/server, the random reverses of the elements simulates the noise of the channel and the altered bit array simulates the received bit array from receiver/client.

Comment: I create arrays in two machine and send array to one of them for comparision. based on the error rate, further processing can be done. Can you please provide some link or something how do we create deterministic PRNG in c++.

Comment: @40two I really did not get your comment. can you please elaborate.

Comment: @user3744763 I suppose having 2 machines is a theoretical construction.

Comment: I agree with @40two here. Either a)you're testing real-life scenarios, in which case you should just accept the received data as-is and calculate the error rate based on whatever error-correction scheme you have; or b)you're simulating an error-prone scenario to test error-correction algorithms, in which case it should all be done on one machine to ensure you *don't* introduce any unknown variables (i.e. actual noise in the channel)

Comment: A common method used to generate random numbers is a [Linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

Comment: @lc, the code will be implemented in real problem. to make you guys clear, I am developing the error correction protocol for security application. if the channel has more than 10 % error , error correction protocol should be aborted. thts why for testing i need to generate bit pattern with less than 10% error bits to apply error correction protocol.

Comment: @Hum You can do it as a part of the unit testing -- change the networking code to one providing the data with artificial error you generate locally.